# How to conditionally show fields on record edit form

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-recordeditform

I am using record-edit-form and want to conditionally show fields on change of checkbox

HTML

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="Line_of_cover_Accident__c" onchange={toggleAccidentFields}> </lightning-input-field>
                    <template if:true={showAccidentFields}>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Annual_Premium_Accident__c" required> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Number_of_Lives_Accident__c" required> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Accident_Policy_Number_s__c" required> </lightning-input-field>
                    </template>
```

JS

```
export default class NetworkSearchSurvey extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId;
        @api networkSearchResponse;
        @api showSurvey = false;
        @api isLoaded = false;
    
        @api get showAccidentFields() {
            return this.networkSearchResponse.fields.Line_of_cover_Accident__c.value;
        }
    
        toggleAccidentFields() {
            this.showAccidentFields = !this.showAccidentFields;
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is that my getter runs when `toggleAccidentFields()` is triggered and just overrides anything done there but I'm not sure how to overcome this.

I tried just setting `showAccidentFields = false;` but that means that if the record is marked true and saved then the fields are hidden on the next load of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even have a setter, so `this.showAccidentFields = !this.showAccidentFields` would fail. Further, the `@api` property would make it read-only, even if you had a setter.

If you need to expose the field as a public property, use a backing variable with both a get and set:

```
_showAccidentFields;
@api get showAccidentFields() {
  return this._showAccidentFields;
}
set showAccidentFields(value) {
  this._showAccidentFields = value;
}
toggleAccidentFields() {
  this._showAccidentFields = !this._showAccidentFields;
}
```

If you *don't* need to expose showAccidentFields as a public property, you can:

```
    _networkSearchResponse;
    @api set networkSearchResponse(value) {
      this._networkSearchResponse = value;
      if(value) {
        this.showAccidentFields = value.fields.Line_of_cover_Accident__c.value;
      }
    }
    get networkSearchResponse() {
      return this._networkSearchResponse;
    }
    showAccidentFields = false;
    toggleAccidentFields() {
        this.showAccidentFields = !this.showAccidentFields;
    }
```

Note: I'd suggest using [getFieldValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_get_field_value) or [getFieldDisplayValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_display_value) as appropriate, instead of relying on a direct reference to the value.

Comment: thanks for this, worked perfectly! Getter/setter is not something I've used before so need to learn more about it.